# Posted custom messages are never received by my form

Tags: delphi, postmessage

I'm using `PostMessage` to send messages from another unit to the main form, like this:

```
procedure notify(var Message: TMessage); message 1;
```

In the procedure, information is shown according to `WParam`:

```
procedure TForm1.notify(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Case (Message.WParam) of
    1: memo1.Lines.Add('task started');
    2: memo1.Lines.Add('in progress');
  end;
end;
```

In the other unit I send messages like this:

```
PostMessage(Handle, 1, 2, variable_info);
```

First of all, what is message ID? I replaced it by 1 because its type is cardinal, what should I use instead? And my messages are never received, because `Message.WParam` is never equal to 1 or 2. What is wrong in my code?

---

I edited my code like this: unit1

```
 const
 WM_MY_MESSAGE = WM_USER + 0;
```

in the code I added something like this:

```
 PostMessage(Handle,WM_MY_MESSAGE, 1,value_sent);
```

TFormUnit:

```
  private
  procedure notify(var Message :TMessage); message WM_MY_MESSAGE;

  procedure TFormMain.notify(var Message: TMessage);
  begin
  Case (Message.WParam)of // which is 1
   1:
  //------------------------------------------
  begin
   memo1.Lines.Add('task started');
```

Normally when PostMessage(Handle,WM_MY_MESSAGE, 1,value_sent); is executed I should get the message 
task started, but it's the same error, nothing happens!

Comment: That's `WM_CREATE`. You aren't allowed to send that asynchronously. The system knows that.

Comment: see also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596047/how-to-define-private-base-application-messages

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [message ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#app_defined) must be unique. For sending messages within an application, use the constant `WM_USER` (declared in the `Messages` unit) as the first valid starting number.

Values below `WM_USER` ($0400) are reserved for system-defined messages. 
From documentation:

> Applications cannot use these values for private messages.

Declare this in the interface section of your form or in a unit with all other messages in your application.

```
const 
  WM_MY_MESSAGE = WM_USER + 0;
```

Edit:

In an addition to the question, to get the form window handle in your PostMessage call,

```
PostMessage(YourForm.Handle,WM_MY_MESSAGE,1,value_sent);
```

or

```
PostMessage(FindWindow(nil,'YourFormName'),WM_MY_MESSAGE,1,value_sent);
```